# How to solve Zebra printer alignment issue?

Tags: zebra-printer

I built a JSF app back a few months ago that prints on a label printer.  We had a demo unit from the manufacturer at the time and everything worked perfect.  Shipped the demo printer back, finally received our production units, and it no longer aligns properly.  The image I'm sending is getting shifted "down" the label about an inch

I verified that the margins are all zero in the printer setup.  Label size is right in printer setup.  Really nothing has changed on the Glassfish server (which prints directly to the printer).  What else should I be looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I had been inserting the paper roll (with built in cardboard tube) directly (not using the Zebra tube) as per the instructions.  When I put the Zebra tube inside the built in tube and used it that way, the alignment came into place.  Makes no sense to me, but that's what did it!